# Why is my header taller than I want it to be, and why aren't my images displaying in an inline manner?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm taking my normal website, http://christianselig.com and converting it to a Wordpress site at http://christianselig.com/wp.

I'm having two issues. My nav menu at the top is of differing height. It has pretty much identical styling, so I can't place why.

Also, my images in my portfolio display in an inline fashion on my main website, but in the Wordpress site - again, despite identical styling - they appear on their own lines, something I don't want.

Could anyone offer a reason as to why these things are happening? I've been a good person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are displaying on their own lines because there is a `<br/>` after each image.

As for your navigation. If you remove `.main-navigation a { display: block }` and add padding to the active `li` it will be the same.

Comment: But there aren't. I'm using Wordpress, so maybe it's inserting automatically, but my code looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/8fxa8.png

Comment: Wordpress is adding the `<br />` you can add `#portfolio-images br {display:none;}` Its a silly hack but it should work.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Since I had a linebreak is the WYSIWYG editor, it assumed I wanted a br tag. Heaven forbid I have my code organized.

Answer (score 0):

Your images aren't inline as there are line breaks between them. Wordpress puts these in automatically. Try the [raw html](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/) plugin to get around this.